# Camunda BOM Version Issue

Tags: camunda

I am trying to use Camunda and spring and following the tutorial [here](https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/spring/project-setup/).

In our project we use enforcer to ensure we don't have different versions of the same jars being into the class path. When I create my pom exactly like Camunda specifies my build fails because of different versions, specifically on the camunda-commons-typed-values and -logging jars. In some places it uses version 1.3.0 specified in the BOM and in other places it uses version 1.2.0 hard-coded into the dependency..

I am not sure how I should get around this (disabling enforcer is not an option). Which version should be used? Why is version 1.2.0 sometimes hard-coded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apologies this was just me being a knob. In our multi layer project i had the BOM specified in a camunda module that i imported into another module. That caused the build to fail with the version issue. I then moved the BOM out of the module into a parent that is common to both the camunda module and the module importing it, and now it works